# rs.next() is always returning false

Tags: java

There are entries in the database but whenever i enter any valid or invalid details in login form it always displays login failed. rs.next() is always returning false. Any solution for this problem ?

Code is as follows:-

```
try {
    
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/logindata","root","");
    
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    
    String sql ="Select * from login Where UserName=' " + textField.getText()+ " 'and Password= ' " + passwordField.getText().toString()+"'";
    PreparedStatement stmt =con.prepareStatement(sql);
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
    
    String id=null;
    String userId=null;
    
    while(rs.next())
    {
    id=rs.getString("UserName");
   userId=rs.getString("Password");
   }

   if(id!=null)
   System.out.println("Login Success");
   else
   System.out.println("Login Failed");
   
   
    con.close();    
}
catch(Exception ex) {
    System.out.println(ex);
}
```

Comment: You are surrounding your password and user with spaces.

Comment: It might be better to use a PreparedStatement.